# Trigger link on tap within touch event

Tags: javascript, mobile

I'm building a tablet version of a website. I am using custom touchevents to detect swiping and moving a HTML element accordingly. With the HTML element is an A tag with an HREF. On an iPad, when I tap the link, it does not go to the URL.

What is the best method to trigger a link within a touchevent?

[Check Out](http://jsbin.com/kajequlo/1/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Hopefully, this question/answer will help someone else out...I had some difficulty finding a good answer out there.

Stole the util.click snippet from iScroll (https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/blob/master/src/utils.js).

```
function click(e) {
    var target = e.target,
        ev;

    if ( !(/(SELECT|INPUT|TEXTAREA)/i).test(target.tagName) ) {
        ev = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        ev.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, e.view, 1,
            target.screenX, target.screenY, target.clientX, target.clientY,
            e.ctrlKey, e.altKey, e.shiftKey, e.metaKey,
            0, null);

        ev._constructed = true;
        target.dispatchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```